# Magento2: How to call custom block in phtml file

Tags: magento2, custom-block

I have created a custom block page. I want to call custom block to another phtml file.

When I called custom block in xml file is working.

But when I called custom block in phtml file is not working.

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Codism\Csr\Block\Index\TopMenu')
    ->setBlockId('Codism_Csr::menu.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: Is there any error or system.log?

Comment: No errors in system log file.\

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call phtml like this below way :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Codism\Csr\Block\Index\TopMenu')
    ->setTemplate('Codism_Csr::menu.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Codism\Csr\Block\Index\TopMenu')
    ->setTemplate('Codism_Csr::menu.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: What is diff in my code?

Comment: You need to use setTemplate() instead of setBlockId()

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
echo $block->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Codism\Csr\Block\Index\TopMenu')
          ->setTemplate('Codism_Csr::menu.phtml')
          ->toHtml();
```

You are not using `setTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **setTemplate** instead of **setBlockId**