# Add custom template in listing page - Magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, product-list

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

How can I remove the attributes that appear for each product and add a new template which contains different styles and content?

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html
Is it exactly what you need?

Comment: in magento the attribute call part is used here for example file vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml ``` <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?> ```

Comment: I think not, I am using a theme to make these modifications, and what I want is to remove all the components that are there and add some with different styles. It should be noted that I want to do this on the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You need to overrite  magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml file.**

> **For Theme**

**app/design/frontend/VednoreName/ModuleName/Magento_Catalog/layout**

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **For Module**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: For Call Custom Block https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249055/magento2-how-to-call-custom-block-in-phtml-file

Comment: How can I do that but from a theme ? And delete de others elements like wish lish, compare products, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot. However, the changes I want to make are on the home page. When creating a new theme it does not show items on this page, so I made use of the page builder to show products and it is just that widget that I want to modify.